# Applications of Eckmann-Hilton argument to topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, at.algebraic-topology

There have been a couple of [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8883#8883) and [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35868/fundamental-group-of-lie-groups) on MathOverflow about the proofs of the following two facts:

**Fact 1**: if $X$ is a topological space, then $\pi_k(X,x)$ is abelian for $k\ge 2$.

**Fact 2**: if $G$ is a topological group, then $\pi_1(G,e)$ is abelian.

Both facts can be proven using the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument), which is a cool algebraisation of two more topological proofs that one can get by staring for sufficiently long to a couple of pictures* (after drawing them): while, up until two hours ago, I thought that the two proofs were actually distinct, Ryan Budney proved me wrong and showed me the connection (see comments below)

Now, to the question:

> Is there any other example of an incursion of the Eckmann-Hilton argument into the realm of topology? Is there any other such application outside category theory/algebra?

I would like to see some results for which no proof is known that doesn't make use of the E-H argument, or such that any proof avoiding the argument (even somehow disguised) is significantly longer/harder.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Ryan Budney for pointing out how the two kind of proofs are actually the same proof, and to Tom Goodwillie for making me realise that the question was a bit too rough in an earlier version.

---

* One such picture is linked above. The other one is just a square with the diagonal, representing the map $(s,t)\mapsto (f(s),g(t))$: this picture gives homotopies between $f\cdot g$ and $f*g$, so they recover as much information as the E-H argument produces, see the question linked above.

Comment: I don't see much of a question here -- the Eckmann-Hilton argument is equivalent to the argument with the pictures you suggest.  One is couched in more verbal/algebraic language, the other in more direct geometric language.  But it's essentially the same argument in that the same homotopies are ultimately used in the Eckmann-Hilton argument, they're just decorated in a different way. 

Comment: "Intrusion", huh? I could just as well say that the topological proof conceals the fact that it's really an instance of Eckmann-Hilton. But I'd rather say that the choice is a matter of taste, and that for me the two points of view are nicely complementary.

Comment: @Ryan Budney: I struggle to see homotopies in the proof of the E-H argument (that doesn't mean that they're not there). Could you expand a bit? Also, I'm editing the question, trying to make it a bit softer. -- @Tom Goodwillie: I just wanted to make clear "which side I'm on". I agree that it's nice to have both viewpoints, and I quite like the tricky proof. Nevertheless, I feel like the "topological" proof is more instructive for -say- an undergraduate student learning algebraic topology.

Comment: When you say something like $\pi_k(X,x)$ is abelian, that's saying there's a homotopy between the representatives for $ab$ and $ba$.  The Wikipedia article you cite describes how to go from $ab$ to $ba$, and there are various ingredient steps like $a=a.1$ (this is itself an argument that there is a homotopy of representatives) and such.  Assemble all these ingredient homotopies into the argument that $ab=ba$ and you get the same picture.  The Wikipedia page strangely says this picture is more satisfying, yet it does not give it.  

Comment: Thanks, Ryan: I hadn't thought it that way. I've edited the question according to your (and Tom's) remarks. Is it a more sensible question, now?

Comment: If $E$ is an $E_\infinity$ ring spectrum (actually $E_2$ is enough) then the $E$-homology of a 2-fold loop space is a commutative $E_*$-algebra. This is merely a stable version of the facts you mention so this is probably not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't resist pointing out that while the EH-argument shows that a group object in the category of groups is an abelian group, this does not apply to a group object in the category of groupoids, which is equivalent instead to a crossed module, which represents a pointed, connected homotopy 2-type.

Higher groupoids are in some sense ``more nonabelian'' than groups, and provide a route to some nonabelian calculations in higher homotopy theory.

So circumstances in which the EH-argument fails (for example a group object in the category of semigroups) are maybe more interesting.

Comment: I should modify that comment. The EH-argument can also be phrased as using the ``interchange law''. This is fundamental in its general form for multiple groupoids, and their applications in homotopy theory, and higher dimensional algebra; it allows what we can call ``algebraic inverses to subdivision'', that is multiple subdivisions and compositions. Here the cubical apparatus is easiest to apply.  

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any specific example of such "nonabelian calculations in higher homotopy theory"?

Comment: See Part I of our new book downloadable from 

http://www.bangor.ac.uk/r.brown/nonab-a-t.html

which calculates homotopy 2-types as crossed modules, using a 2-d van Kampen theorem; most of the  114 papers on the nonabelian tensor product listed on 
...../r.brown/nonabtens.html 

and for example a recent paper 

Ellis, G.J. and Mikhailov, R. A colimit of classifying spaces.
Advances in Math.  (2010) arXiv: [math.GR] 0804.3581v1 1--16.

uses these nonabelian techniques, with references to the background. Some  calculations are in terms of precise nonabelian colimits. (!!!)



Comment: Let me give a simple example. Let $f: G \to H$ be a morphism of groups. Then we have a map of classifying spaces $Bf: BG \to BH$ and we would like to calculate the 2-type of the mapping cone $C(Bf)$. The 2d-van Kampen theorem implies this 2-type is described by an "induced  crossed module" $\partial: f_*(G) \to H$ and there are methods of calculating this explicitly, sometimes needing computational group theory. From this (nonabelian) information you can calculate $\pi_2(C(Bf),x)$ as Ker $\partial$ as a module over $\pi_1$. 

There seems no other way to obtain this information.  